# Error creating bean with name 'solverManager', Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, optaplanner

[JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) is a development platform to quickly generate, develop, & deploy modern web applications & microservice architectures using Spring-boot framework.
Jhipster has "straight to go" script to deploy on google cloud.

[Optaplanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/) is an AI library which helps solve planning and scheduling problems.

My goal is to use Jhipster to develop quickly a platform which resort to optaplanner to solve a specific problem, and finally deploy the code on Google Kubernate.
I finally come with a solution by merging examples codes from [Optaplanner](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/technology/java-spring-boot) and Jhipster.

As shown in the folowing output, it works well on my machine on local.After installing Jhipster :

```
jhipster 
mvn package -Pprod jib:dockerBuild 
java -jar target/jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

```
:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.5.4 ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

23:14:22.340  INFO [main           ] The following profiles are active: prod
23:14:25.183  INFO [main           ] Web application configuration, using profiles: prod
23:14:25.184  INFO [main           ] Web application fully configured
23:14:31.135 DEBUG [main           ] Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/parfait/Programming/JavaScript/Jhipster/target/jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycompany/myapp/domain/TimeTable.class]
23:14:31.145 DEBUG [main           ] Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/parfait/Programming/JavaScript/Jhipster/target/jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/mycompany/myapp/domain/Lesson.class]
23:14:35.403  INFO [main           ] JBoss Threads version 3.1.0.Final
23:14:35.477  INFO [main           ] Started JhipsterApp in 14.484 seconds (JVM running for 15.042)
23:14:35.479  INFO [main           ] 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'Jhipster' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8080/
    External:   http://127.0.1.1:8080/
    Profile(s):     [prod]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I execute the script to deploy the same code on Google Kuberntes, I face the following error:

```
jhipster k8s 
./mvnw clean compile jib:build 
./mvnw -ntp -Pprod jib:build -Djib.to.image=gcr.io/jhipster17/jhipster 
bash kubectl-apply.sh -f
```

Output from Kubernetes logs:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'timeTableResource' defined in file 
[/app/classes/com/mycompany/myapp/web/rest/TimeTableResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solverManager' defined in class path 
resource [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' 
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) 
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) 
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) 
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) 
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) 
at com.mycompany.myapp.JhipsterApp.main(JhipsterApp.java:69) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'solverManager' defined in class path resource [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ... 
17 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ... 31 common frames omitted Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null at java.compiler@11.0.12/javax.tools.ToolProvider.lambda$matches$0(Unknown Source) 
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.compiler@11.0.12/javax.tools.ToolProvider.matches(Unknown Source) 
at java.compiler@11.0.12/javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemTool(Unknown Source) 
at java.compiler@11.0.12/javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(Unknown Source) 
at org.kie.memorycompiler.jdknative.NativeJavaCompiler.compile(NativeJavaCompiler.java:73) 
at org.kie.memorycompiler.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:41) 
at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compileNoLoad(KieMemoryCompiler.java:129) 
at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compileNoLoad(KieMemoryCompiler.java:101) 
at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compile(KieMemoryCompiler.java:53) 
at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compile(KieMemoryCompiler.java:39) 
at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.inMemoryUpdate(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:66) 
at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.run(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:52) 
at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.generateAndSetInMemoryANC(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:99) 
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.buildKieBaseFromModel(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:115) 
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.buildKieBase(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:104) 
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.<init>(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:71) 
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:223) 
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.decideMultipleScoreDirectorFactories(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:103) 
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:71) 
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:116) 
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolver(DefaultSolverFactory.java:83) 
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.validateSolverFactory(DefaultSolverManager.java:68) 
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.<init>(DefaultSolverManager.java:57) 
at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager.create(SolverManager.java:111) 
at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.solverManager(OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.java:98) 
at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e4db969.CGLIB$solverManager$3(<generated>) 
at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e4db969$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$277961ad.invoke(<generated>) 
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) 
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) 
at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e4db969.solverManager(<generated>) 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ... 32 common frames omitted
```

This is the code for the SolverManager bean injection, based on the Jhipster examples code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TimeTableResource {

    private TimeTableRepository timeTableRepository;

    private SolverManager<TimeTable, Long> solverManager;

    public TimeTableResource(TimeTableRepository timeTableRepository, SolverManager<TimeTable, Long> solverManager) {
        this.timeTableRepository = timeTableRepository;
        this.solverManager = solverManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@code POST  /solve}
     */
    @PostMapping("/solve")
    public void solve(TimeTableRepository timeTableRepository, SolverManager<TimeTable, Long> solverManager) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to solve ");
        solverManager.solveAndListen(TimeTableRepository.SINGLETON_TIME_TABLE_ID, timeTableRepository::findById, timeTableRepository::save);
    }
}
```

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/zackzack02/Jhipster).
I don't understand why this "Unsatisfied dependency" happens when deployed on gke whereas there is no such error on local machine, nor on gce.

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: There is a null pointer exception hiding in there.

Comment: You could try running in k8s locally, where the problem will be easier to debug.

Comment: @tgdavies, The problem does not happen locally

Comment: Even in a container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `NullPointerException` lurking in the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null at java.compiler@11.0.12/javax.tools.ToolProvider.lambda$matches$0(Unknown Source)
```

Having never seen this exception before, I can make an educated guess: could it be that you don't have a Java compiler on the machine? Please install a full JDK (one that brings `javac` as well as `java`) and this problem may go away.

The reason for that is that Constraint Streams - in order to generate the code for your constraints - will need to compile some Java classes into bytecode. And without `javac`, that is not possible.